# how track location using maps in ASP.NET Core razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I want in my web app the customer can track live location and know where their order is when it with delivery, in ASP.NET Core Razor page

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi @Amal, pls share enough code then we can know how to suggest you solve such problem.

Comment: I just try to how can i implementation this idea

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is how to create an extremely complex service, which is something that is impossible to give a simple answer to. In the case you already have created the complete backend of your live location tracking service, and you are just looking for the visual aspect of your solution: then you should search for a service/library which allows you to add GEO maps to your Blazor pages. The library you use for this should also have an option which allows you to add your own data, such as landmarks for the order locations. An example of a service I found online is Azure Maps. I also found a nuget package called [Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Maps) which could be useful.

Comment: thx for your comment, actually I want to implemtion this idea because, in my web app, I want the customer to be able to track their order when it is delivered to the representative, to know when the order will arrive and how much time it takes to receive the order,
, and I use a razor not blazor 

if u have any suggestions about this idea u can tell me 

thank u!